# How to apply a function of several arguments to a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have a list of triplets:

```
list = {{1, 3, 5}, {4, 5, 1}, {4, 9, 2}}
```

How can I apply a function f to the last element of each triplet when f the last and second-to-last elements of each triplet as arguments? The result should look like:

> ```
> {{1, 3, f[3, 5]}, {4, 5, f[5, 1]}, {4, 9, f[9, 2]}}
> ```

I tried:

```
list /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, b, f[b, c]}
```

But the result comes out as

> ```
> {{1, 3, 5}, {4, 5, 1}, {f[4], f[9], f[2]}}
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it.

```
data = {{1, 3, 5}, {4, 5, 1}, {4, 9, 2}};
Replace[data, {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, b, f[b, c]}, {1}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3, f[3, 5]}, {4, 5, f[5, 1]}, {4, 9, f[9, 2]}}
> ```

```
MapThread[{#1, #2, f[#2, #3]} &, data]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3, f[3, 5]}, {4, 5, f[5, 1]}, {4, 9, f[9, 2]}}
> ```

A small variant of the last is

```
MapThread[{#1, #2, f[##2]} &, data]
```

Answer (score 5):

When the sublists are short like in your example, I tend to use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html):

```
 {#1, #2, f[#2, #3]}& @@@ {{1, 3, 5}, {4, 5, 1}, {4, 9, 2}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{#[[1]], #[[2]], f[#[[2]], #[[3]]]} & /@ {{1, 3, 5}, {4, 5, 1}, {4, 9, 2}}
```

> {{1, 3, f[3, 5]}, {4, 5, f[5, 1]}, {4, 9, f[9, 2]}}

Answer (score 2):

```
# /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, b, f[b, c]} & /@ list
```